# Find the maximum absolute value in a list

Tags: python, absolute-value

I'm looking to get the maximum absolute value in a random list. I need to create it in a function. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have a for loop setup so it should check each number but it's only returning the first value.

```
def main():
    print(maxabsinlst([-19, -3, 20, -1, 5, -25]))

def maxabsinlst(num):
    for x in (num):
        max_abs_value = num[5]
        if abs(x) > max_abs_value:
            max_abs_value = abs(x)
            return max(abs(max_abs_value))

main()
```

Comment: It's not returning the first value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from show up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

The shortest way would be:

```
def maxabsinlst(num):
    return max(map(abs, num))
```

The `map()` function applies `abs()` to each number on the list, and returns a list of these absolute values, then `max()` finds the maximum in the list.

Comment: You're still using Python 2?

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. I'm using Python 3 here.

Comment: In Python 3 it's not a list.

Comment: @superbrain What are you talking about? This is python3?

Comment: In Python 3, `map` doesn't return a list.

Comment: Does it matter?  It gets immediately passed into `max`.

Comment: @DanielWalker I'd say if it didn't matter, they wouldn't have changed it :-)

Comment: @DanielWalker Or if you meant whether it mattered here... well, I'd say it matters to not misinform readers.

Comment: Ah, I understand.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning `max_abs_value` to `num[5]` inside the loop. Instead assign it as first element of list then loop through it comparing with other elements

```
def main():
    print(maxabsinlst([-19, -3, 20, -1, 5, -25]))

def maxabsinlst(num):
    max_abs_value = abs(num[0])
    for x in num[1:]:
        if abs(x) > max_abs_value:
            max_abs_value = abs(x)
    return max_abs_value

main()
```

OR

```
In [36]: max(abs(i) for i in [-19, -3, 20, -1, 5, -25])
Out[36]: 25
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make this quite a bit more concise:

```
def max_abs_in_lst(num):
    num = [abs(i) for i in num]
    return max(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

`max_abs_value = num[5]`

Every time the for loop runs, it is setting the max value to -25. Store the value outside the for loop and initialize it with `max_abs_value = 0`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your function.  First, you're setting `max_abs_value` at every iteration of the `for` loop.  Second, you're assuming that the list passed to the function will have length 6 every time.  Third, you never computed the absolute value of `num[5]`.  So, you're comparing `abs(x)` to a negative number.  Fourth, you're returning from the function as soon as you find **any** value greater than `max_abs_value`.  You have no guarantee that it was the the greatest value in the list.

What you want is

```
def maxabsinlist(num):
    max_abs_value=abs(num[0])
    for x in num[1:]:
        value=abs(x)
        if value > max_abs_value:
            max_abs_value=value
    return max_abs_value
```